# Use reflection to use constants for Calender class to add months

Tags: java, reflection, static, calendar, constants

Suppose we have array of String having values ("MONTH=12","DAY_OF_MONTH=10")
so depending upon input condition i need to add either add month/days/hours to myDate

eg 1. if need to add 12 months to date i need to do below
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,12);

eg 2. If i need to add 10 days 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,12);

I can do above using If condition for each case if String = MONTH use Calender.MONTH, if it is DAY_OF_MONTH use Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH

So i want to achieve this by Reflection so that i don't need to put if conditions

Comment: Why don't you just create a `Map<String,Integer>`?

Comment: Can you provide more details ?how exactly ?

Comment: By the way, a completely different approach is to use use `Period` and `Duration` objects to represent your months to add, days to add, etc. rather than mere strings. `Period.ofMonths( 12 )` or `Period.ofDays( 10 )`, then add: `LocalDate.now().plus( period )`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`getField(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) on the `Calendar` class, and then call [`Field.get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) with `null` to get the class field(s). Something like,

```
String toGet = "DAY_OF_MONTH";
try {
    Field f = Calendar.class.getField(toGet);
    Integer v = (Integer) f.get(null);
    System.out.printf("%d == %d%n", v, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs

```
5 == 5
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott, But Build failed: inconvertible types
    [javac] found   : java.lang.Object
    [javac] required: int
    [javac]          int v = (int) f.get(null)

Comment: @user1415985 Edited. I did test the code, what version of Java are you using?

Comment: java -showversion
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Hi Ellott,I used getInt and it worked :) thanks for showing the path